# Delete a file tree in parallel with Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to delete a file tree in parallel with Rust. I'm using jwalk for parallel traversal and deletion of files. The code shown below deletes all the files. In general it's working as expected, but the performance is terrible.

Compared to a Python version I've implemented, it's 5 times slower on Windows! What am I doing wrong, so that the Rust version is that slow?

What I've found out so far is that `std::fs::remove_file` is the reason for the bad performance. I'm wondering if the implementation of this function has a performance issue, at least on Windows?

I'm using Rust version 1.42.0 with toolchain stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.

```
let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
WalkBuilder::new(tmpr)
    .hidden(false)
    .standard_filters(false)
    .threads(cmp::min(30, num_cpus::get()))
    .build_parallel()
    .run(move || {
        let tx = tx.clone();
        Box::new(move |dir_entry_result| {
            if let Ok(dir_entry) = dir_entry_result {
                if dir_entry.file_type().unwrap().is_dir() {
                    tx.send(dir_entry.path().to_owned()).unwrap();
                } else {
                    if let Err(_) = std::fs::remove_file(&dir_entry.path()) {
                        match fix_permissions(&dir_entry.path()) {
                            Ok(_) => {
                                if let Err(_) = std::fs::remove_file(&dir_entry.path()) {
                                    tx.send(dir_entry.path().to_owned()).unwrap();
                                }
                            }
                            Err(_) => {
                                tx.send(dir_entry.path().to_owned()).unwrap();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ignore::WalkState::Continue
        })
    });
let paths: Vec<_> = rx.into_iter().collect();
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Deleting a directory tree is almost certainly I/O-bound, and throwing multiple CPUs at it will probably slow it down, since you will have more contention for the device.

Comment: No, parallelization of I/O operations does not slow down, at least on SSDs. I've already paralellized different kind of I/O operations, which already brought a speedup. On Linux the speedup is factor 2-3. On Windows the speedup can be up to a factor >10.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason for the slowdown. It was the virus scanner. The reason why the Python version was faster is that Python.exe is ignored by the virus scanner, but the Rust exe not. After I disabled the virus scanner the Rust version is now lightning fast.